# Change language of TFS 2012 after installation

Tags: tfs

I just installed a new Team Foundation Server 2012 in its English version. Is it possible to switch to another language?

I need this for changing the language of the process templates used by the server. Maybe its possible to just update them and leave the server in English?

I'm a little bit afraid of running the upgrade on this machine because I don't know, if upgrade can also mean TFS 2012 EN -> TFS 2012 OTHER.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to take the risk and I did following:

1. Uninstall TFS 2012 German completely.
2. Start Setup from TFS 2012 German Image
3. Choose "Upgrade"-Option when the first installation is done.
4. After Setup don't forget to re-configure things like build.

For those of you who think: "Why the hell...?": I installed the english version and recognized, that I could not use some conversion-tools. If you for instance try to bring "My Work" online, it complains when you switched language. Thats why this was so important to me.

After all I got some strange errors on my dashboard. I figured out that the OLAP-Cube was not able to be rebuilt due to some translation problems. The solution for this is:

1. Use SQL Server Management Studio and log on to the Analysis Services module.
2. Exand the databases-node and delete the Tfs_Analysis-database.
3. Open TFS Administration Console from the start menu.
4. Got to Application Tier -> Reporting and click "Edit" in the right pane.
5. Got to the second tab "Analysis" and re-enter all informations leaving the database-name as it is.
6. Click "Ok". In SQL Management Studio you should see the recreated Tfs_Analysis-database.
7. Go back to TFS Admin Console and click on "Recreate" in the right pane.
8. Go to SQL Management Studio, expand the Nodes Tfs_Analysis -> Cubes and right-click on the "Team System"-node.
9. Hit the third option (I don't know the english name but should be something like "Process".
   If no error is shown, your cube should work now.

Comment: Did you therefore succeed in using another language for your processes?

Comment: @Jeremie I think yes. It's just hard to remember this 5 years later :-).